# i need to add matTooltip in mat-tab without icon angular 8 and angular material is used

Tags: angular

Is there any way to add ***tooltip*** without icon in mat-tab?

I am trying to implement a tooltip in angular material mat-tab but the tooltip is not working without mat-icon

Below is the code :

```
<mat-tab label="Application Request" matTooltip="Info about the action" >
```

Comment: ```<mat-tab label="Application Request" matTooltip="Info about the action" >```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer tooltip will display in span code is

````
                                    <span class="sg-mat-txt" matTooltip="Application Request" aria-label="">Application Request</span>
                                  </ng-template>```
````

Answer (score 1):

Quoting material documentation

> For more complex labels, add a template with the mat-tab-label
>   directive inside the mat-tab.

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      The <em>best</em> pasta
    </ng-template>
    <h1>Best pasta restaurants</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon> The worst sushi
    </ng-template>
    <h1>Terrible sushi restaurants</h1>
    <p>...</p>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Basically the same thing applies for tooltip and any other material component if you want to make the tab more complicated.

Comment: i have mentioned in my Question that  add tooltip without icon in mat-tab

Comment: Ok, can you please explain what you mean? Do you want to use mat-icon with mat-tab or not? What do you meant exactly by "not working"?

Comment: i need to apply tooltip without mat-icon on mat-tab in your answer tootlip is not applied